# DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table', RESEED, 0) is causing he INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one one parent table which has the id column with the Identity defined.

```
CREATE TABLE [model].[Parent](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL)
```

Now I have another child table table which refer parent Id column

```
CREATE TABLE [model].[Child](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ParentId] [int] NULL)
GO
ALTER TABLE [model].[Child]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentIdentity] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [model].[Parent] ([Id])
GO
```

Both table has the id as primary key. Now the issue is when I am doing the migration I set the

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Model].[Parent]', RESEED, 0)
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Model].[Child]', RESEED, 0)
```

I use the dynamic query to generate the insert statement.

Now the when I insert the first row , I insert with the Null value in child table for Parent.id and get the following error :

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ParentIdentity". The conflict occurred in database "DBName", table "model.Parent", column 'Id'.
>   Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL'.

Can any one help me with this, I saw many solutions but did not help me. I don't have an option to delete the table and create it again.

Comment: Are your tables empty when you try to insert your first child row? Can you add an example of your actions after the DBCC CHECKINDENT?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with `insert into Child values ('test', null)`, but I did have to replace `IDENTITY(1,1)` with `primary key IDENTITY(1,1)` for both tables.

Comment: Nicolas R@ Yes , After DBCC I insert the data to the chiled table. Parent has the data before I insert into child.

Comment: Stijn@ We do it like this : CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentIdentity] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
). Try using DBCC just before you insert the data. FYI..I added is as sample for my question, my table is bigger and cant post it here.

Comment: Have you tried putting a GO or commit statement between your DBCC statements and your INSERT?

Comment: Actually I am using SQLCLR from .net to perform the operation and they do not support GO.

Comment: First - try using cascade update on the constraint. Otherwise you'll need to rework your data in pairs, manually and not by reseeding. Possible what you need to do is copy data into new tables while iterating over the two and once done - move the data back to the right table.

Comment: Allan@could you elaborate more pls.

Comment: You nee to address people with @name instead of name@, or they won't get a notification.